# Rails routing / assets with proxied location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

OK so - I have a rails app, let's call it "railsapp", on a domain on a Dreamhost VPS (on which I have other domains, some 'static' and one that serves a perl/CGI script).

For obvious reasons, Passenger cannot be run on port 80, and is currently serving this app on port 8001. I have a proxy (configured in Apache) set up to route requests for `http://DOMAIN/books` to `DOMAIN:8001/` (which, incidentally, works as `DOMAIN/railsapp`).

The issues:

1) No assets are served - the request for the stylesheets 404s, despite the fact that the stylesheets do in fact exist in `[railsapp]/public/assets`. I have tried every possible combination of precompiling, *not* precompiling, etc., and nothing seems to work.

2) Links aren't working exactly right. Accessed explicitly through port 8001, links work correctly, e.g., `DOMAIN:8001/about` shows the 'about' page and `DOMAIN:8001/[railsapp]/[:id]` brings me to the appropriate item.  Similarly, accessed explicitly (i.e., by manually typing the address in the address bar), `DOMAIN/books/[railsapp]/[:id]` and `DOMAIN/books/about` work perfectly fine. But the links at `DOMAIN/books` (to the items identified by id) all point to `DOMAIN/[railsapp]/[:id]`, which gives me a 404; the link to 'about', similarly pointing to `DOMAIN/about`, also does not work.

Now! If I were to throw caution to the wind and switch my VPS to use nginx instead of Apache, guess what? The pathing mostly works! Items identified by id are linked as `DOMAIN/books/[railsapp]/[:id]` and "about" is linked as `DOMAIN/books/about`, and this is great. The only issue *in the rails app* is that links back to root are inexplicably(?) rendered as links to `127.0.0.1:8001`. This is annoying, but seems like it would be trivial to fix.  The one problem with this is—you may remember this from the beginning of this post—the VPS also hosts a site that uses perl/CGI, and this is *broken as hell* given that nginx isn't really meant to deal with perl/CGI. As such, I'm sticking with Apache so that the CGI remains unbroken.

*I have done the search for this issue, many times, in many different ways*. I have probably seen whichever stackoverflow question or blog post you are thinking about linking me to. If ***you*** have any idea how to fix the pathing and assets issues, given the above information, let me know.

Comment: This doesn't really look like a `perl` question. I'm also not sure it's actually on topic either, given it's not really about coding.

Comment: It's not about perl - that tag was accidental, and I have removed it. Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason against specifying the port explicitly? Because DOMAIN/anything would be expected to access port 80. Or, where possible, to use relative links?

Comment: Re: port - that's entirely an aesthetic decision on my part. If the answer to my question is "There is literally no way to make this app visible without the port in the URL, given the constraints of the server it's running on", then, well, OK, but I have a hard time believing that. There must be something I'm missing.

Re: relative links - the links are being generated by rails - I *could* change them, but the fact that they work under nginx makes me think it could be easily solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in application.rb inside "class Application < Rails::Application":

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {host: 'DOMAIN/books', port: 80}
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'DOMAIN/books'
config.serve_static_files = true # for rails4; for rails3 use .serve_static_assets = true
```

After that, restart your application.

Make sure that application uses *_url-helpers everywhere rather than *_path-helpers (i. e. root_url instead of root_path)

Comment: OK, wow, thank you! This gets me 90% of the way there. I'm still having problems with the links produced - links to root_url appropriately go to `DOMAIN/books`, but links to "about" and individual items with ids still go to `DOMAIN/about` and `DOMAIN/[railsapp]/[id]` rather than `DOMAIN/books/about` and `DOMAIN/books/[railsapp]/[id]`, respectively. Sincerely grateful that you got me this far.

Comment: **Update:** between your answer and some sleuthing on my own, I was able to suss out where I was going wrong with my links. Cheers.